# SDLmain linking issues using CMake for Clion on OS X

Tags: cmake, sdl

I'm trying to link SDLmain with CMakeLists on CLion.
OpenGL, GLEW and GLUT have been successfully linked, however SDLmain has problems.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Mario)

set(GL_ROOT /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework)
set(GL_INC ${GL_ROOT}/Headers)
set(GL_LIB ${GL_ROOT}/Libraries/libGL.dylib)

set(GLEW_VER 1.13.0)
set(GLEW_ROOT /usr/local/Cellar/glew/${GLEW_VER})
set(GLEW_INC ${GLEW_ROOT}/include/GL)
set(GLEW_LIB ${GLEW_ROOT}/lib/libGLEW.dylib)

set(GLUT_VER 2.8.1)
set(GLUT_ROOT /usr/local/Cellar/freeglut/${GLUT_VER})
set(GLUT_INC ${GLUT_ROOT}/include/GL)
set(GLUT_LIB ${GLUT_ROOT}/lib/libGLUT.dylib)

set(SDL_VER 1.2.15)
set(SDL_ROOT /usr/local/Cellar/sdl/${SDL_VER})
set(SDL_INC ${SDL_ROOT}/include/SDL)
set(SDL_LIB ${SDL_ROOT}/lib/libSDL.dylib)

set(SDL_IMG_VER 1.2.12_2)
set(SDL_IMG_ROOT /usr/local/Cellar/sdl_image/${SDL_IMG_VER})
set(SDL_IMG_INC ${SDL_IMG_ROOT}/include/SDL)
set(SDL_IMG_LIB ${SDL_IMG_ROOT}/lib/libSDL_image.dylib)

set(SDL_MAIN ${SDL_ROOT}/lib/libSDLmain.a)

include_directories(${GL_INC} ${GLEW_INC} ${GLUT_INC} ${SDL_INC} ${SDL_IMG_INC})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -v")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp ${SDL_MAIN} mario.cpp game.cpp game.h textures.cpp textures.h)
add_executable(Mario ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(Mario ${GL_LIB} ${GLEW_LIB} ${GLUT_LIB} ${SDL_LIB} ${SDL_IMG_LIB} ${SDL_MAIN})
```

**Output:**

```
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.11.0 -o Mario -search_paths_first -headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/Mario.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Mario.dir/mario.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Mario.dir/game.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Mario.dir/textures.cpp.o /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Libraries/libGL.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/glew/1.13.0/lib/libGLEW.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/freeglut/2.8.1/lib/libGLUT.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/sdl/1.2.15/lib/libSDL.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/sdl_image/1.2.12_2/lib/libSDL_image.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/sdl/1.2.15/lib/libSDLmain.a -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.3.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CFBundleCopyBundleURL", referenced from:
      -[SDLMain setupWorkingDirectory:] in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
  "_CFBundleGetInfoDictionary", referenced from:
      _main in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
  "_CFBundleGetMainBundle", referenced from:
      -[SDLMain setupWorkingDirectory:] in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
      _main in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
  "_CFRelease", referenced from:
      -[SDLMain setupWorkingDirectory:] in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
  "_CFURLCreateCopyDeletingLastPathComponent", referenced from:
      -[SDLMain setupWorkingDirectory:] in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
  "_CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation", referenced from:
      -[SDLMain setupWorkingDirectory:] in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
  "_CPSEnableForegroundOperation", referenced from:
      _main in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
  "_CPSGetCurrentProcess", referenced from:
      _main in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
  "_CPSSetFrontProcess", referenced from:
      _main in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
  "_NSAllocateMemoryPages", referenced from:
      -[NSString(ReplaceSubString) stringByReplacingRange:with:] in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
  "_NSApp", referenced from:
      _main in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
  "_NSDeallocateMemoryPages", referenced from:
      -[NSString(ReplaceSubString) stringByReplacingRange:with:] in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSApplication", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_NSApplication_$_SDLApplication in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
      objc-class-ref in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAutoreleasePool", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMenu", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMenuItem", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_SDLMain in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSProcessInfo", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSString", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_NSString_$_ReplaceSubString in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
      objc-class-ref in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SDLMain in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
  "___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
      CFString in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
      CFString in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
      CFString in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
      CFString in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
      CFString in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
      CFString in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
      CFString in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
      ...
  "__objc_empty_cache", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SDLMain in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_SDLMain in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
  "_objc_msgSend", referenced from:
      -[SDLMain application:openFile:] in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
      -[SDLMain applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
      -[NSString(ReplaceSubString) stringByReplacingRange:with:] in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
      _main in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

GLEW, GLUT, SDL are *`brew`* installed.
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-framework Cocoa` to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the variables `SDL_VER`, `SDL_INC`, `SDL_LIB` manually. Use `find_package(SDL)`. If this does not automatically finds SDL, pass `SDL_ROOT` to CMake with `cmake -DSDL_ROOT=path/to/sdl` but for brew installed packages, CMake is able to find these.

Documentation for FindSDL: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/FindSDL.html

Same for GLEW and GLUT.